# MS word mail merge "&amp;"

Tags: sql-server, ms-word

I have a mail merge document which is displaying the html escape &"amp;" instead of just simply "&" wherever I have ampersands.

I have confirmed that the character value in the the db is most definitely just a plain ampersand (&).

In my data set SQL is there some kind of replace I can do (or something else) that will allow Word to properly display "&"?

This seems like an odd bug as & is such a common character. Admittedly, I have very little MS Word Mail Merge experience, but I did due diligence searching for this bug on the net and could not find any existing solutions.

Comment: Is the mail format HTML or plain text?   For HTML, this is the proper behavior...

Answer (score -2):

If you have the freedom to change your SQL data, and you are sure that the data is almost always going to show up in HTML format, then you can do it like this:

```
update table_name set string_column_containing_& = 
replace(string_column_containing_&, '&', '&amp;') 
where string_column_containing_& like '%&%'
```

You can also do a similar replace in your .net logic (server side) before you display the data set. I am not familiar with .Net, so can't help you there.

Comment: Don't change DB data to handle display issues, let the display layers worry about display issues.